# df.style: ¿Cómo aplicar negrita a filas completas?

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con un df que estoy pasando a html (para luego hacerlo png). Mi problema es que no encuentro la forma de hacer que filas específicas (1 y 7) del df, se pongan en negrita ("bold").`\033[1m` es lo que encontré en internet especifica negrita. ¿Se pone esto en color? o hay otra forma utilizando df.style?

De momento tengo esto (en "#" se señala donde me está arrojando error python).

```
html = df.style\
         .set_properties(**{'width': 200, 'background-color': '#eae2d5',
                            'color': 'black', 'font-size': '14px',
                            'text-align': 'left'},
                         subset=['var1'])\
         .set_properties(**{'color': '\033[1m'},  # BOLDING rows 1   
                         subset=['var1'][0])\   # Here is the error.    .
         .set_properties(**{'color': '\033[1m'},  # BOLDING rows 7   
                         subset=['var1'][7])\   # Here is the error.              
         .set_properties(**{'width': 80, 'background-color': '#eae2d5',
                            'color': 'black', 'font-size': '14px',
                            'text-align': 'center'},
                         subset=['var3', 'var4'])\
         .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'thead',
                             'props': [('background-color', '#b2361e'),
                                       ('color', 'white'),
                                       ('font-size', '18px')]}, ])\
         .highlight_null(null_color='white').hide_index().render()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, esos códigos de escape basados en `\033` son para terminales ANSI (cualquier emulador de terminal moderno lo soporta), pero no para HTML.

En realidad, lo que puedes fijar a través de `df.style` son atributos CSS y el utilizado para la negrita sería  `"font-weight": "bold"`

Lo segundo, tienes mal los "selectores" (subset) para el caso de querer seleccionar una celda concreta por su columna y fila. Has usado `subset=['var1'][0]`, lo cual  no tiene mucho sentido pues estás "creando" una lista con un solo elemento (`['var1']`) para luego quedarte con ese único elemento al poner detrás `[0]`, con lo que es como si hubieras escrito `subset='var1'`. Y en el siguiente caso es aún peor, pues pones `subset=['var1'][7]` lo cual, como antes, crea una lista de un solo elemento (`['var1']`) para luego seleccionar su elemento 8, que no existe porque como hemos visto tiene un solo elemento, y te dará un `IndexError`.

Para seleccionar una fila y columna concretas, debes usar una tupla, siendo el primer elemento el índice de la fila y el segundo el nombre de la columna. Por tanto, en lugar de `['var1'][0]`  debería ser `(0, 'var1')`, y en l ugar de `['var1'][7]`  ha de ser `(7, 'var1')`. De hecho, puedes seleccionar *a la vez* las filas 0 y 7 con el selector `subset=([0,7], 'var1')`, lo que te permitiría incluso tener en una variable la lista de filas a seleccionar.

Lo tercero, el ancho de la columna debería tener unidades, o será ignorado. Puedes poner por ejemplo `"200px"` en lugar de `200`.

Finalmente, aunque esto no es ya un error sino cuestión de estilo, puedes ahorrarte todos esos `\` al final de ciertas líneas si pones toda la expresión entre paréntesis, pues lo que va dentro de paréntesis python permite que vaya separado en varias líneas.

### Ejemplo

Con todas estas indicaciones, veamos un ejemplo de cómo quedaría.

Primero creo un dataframe con datos de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
ej = [1,2,3,4,5,3,3,4,2,3,4,23,56]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(var1=ej, var2=ej, var3=ej, var4=ej))
```

Que se muestra así con los estilos por defecto:

[image: Tabla ejemplo]

Y le daríamos formato con el siguiente código (tomado del tuyo, pero corregido):

```
html = (df.style
         .set_properties(**{'width': "200px", 'background-color': '#eae2d5',
                            'color': 'black', 'font-size': '14px',
                            'text-align': 'left'},
                         subset="var1")
         .set_properties(**{'font-weight': "bold"}, 
                         subset=([0,7], 'var1'))        
         .set_properties(**{'width': "80px", 'background-color': '#eae2d5',
                            'color': 'black', 'font-size': '14px',
                            'text-align': 'center'},
                         subset=['var3','var4'])
         .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'thead',
                             'props': [('background-color', '#b2361e'),
                                       ('color', 'white'),
                                       ('font-size', '18px')]}, ])
         .highlight_null(null_color='white').hide_index().render()
       )
```

El resultado podríamos visualizarlo en un Jupyter Notebook de la siguiente forma:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(html)
```

lo que mostraría:

[image: Resultado]

En la fuente utilizada apenas se nota, pero la primera y octava fila (índices 0 y 7) tienen la primera celda en negrita.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia!! Justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Gabra He actualizado la respuesta para corregir un error en los anchos de columna y para especificar las filas 0 y 7 en un solo subset.